# cannot talk to amadeus token generation api

Tags: javascript, angular, postman, token, amadeus

I used postman to send a post to amadeus  `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token` . the parameters are

```
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "idstring",
"client_secret": "secretstring"
```

sent in the body and the header is `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` inputted as a key pair in the header section of postman, However am getting the error

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 38196,
            "title": "Resource not found",
            "detail": "The targeted resource doesn't exist",
            "status": 404
        }
    ]
}
```

please I want to know if this url is really working. I want to generate token and test the amadeus api's. I will appreciate your kind assistance

Answer (score 0):

You can find the authorization endpoint already pre-configured in Postman [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2672636/RWEcPfuJ#f85a162b-a405-baed-cf93-d831bdde2342).

Don't hesitate to download directly our [Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2672636/RWEcPfuJ) or to follow [this tutorial](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/how-to-play-with-self-service-apis-with-no-code-using-postman) to learn how to do it step by step.